# Loop through rows to copy data from multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Workbook that imports data from a vendor sheet.
The vendor Worksheet Column A is dynamic.
The import file should copy the appropriate data to an input sheet in my workbook so the data can be verified before transferring to a log.

I loop through all the rows in column A looking for a specific value. Once found I use the OFFSET function to copy data from different columns in the same row. They are not successive columns.

The code works when copying data from one column.

When I try to copy data from each column it returns nothing.

```vb
Sub ImportData()

Dim FileOpen As Variant
Dim OpenBook As Workbook
Dim i As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
FileOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your File & Import Range", FileFilter:="Excel Files(*.xls*),*xls*")

If FileOpen <> False Then

    Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileOpen)

    OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("E11:F100").Replace What:="U", Replacement:=""
    OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("E11:F100").Replace What:="i", Replacement:=""


    'Date & Time
    OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("E9").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input").Range("B10").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("E10").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input").Range("B11").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("F9").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input").Range("C10").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("F10").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input").Range("C11").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    'Plant Name
    OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("B4").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input").Range("D11").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    'pH
    For i = 11 To 100
        If OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & i).Value = "Sales" Then
            OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 5).Copy
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input").Range("B24").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 6).Copy
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input").Range("C24").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 2).Copy
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input").Range("D24").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next i
    OpenBook.Close False
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You copy everything in your loop to the same cell (`B24`)

Comment: Quick tip to clean up this code: Since you're just copying values from one known location to another, you can skip using `.Copy` and just directly assign the values `Destination.Value = Source.Value`. Heres an example using your first copy paste: `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input").Range("B10").Value = OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("E9").Value`

Comment: Even after your edit, all loops are putting their data into the same cells of row 24. If it finds more than one "Sales", the second will overwrite the first, the third will overwrite the second and so on and so forth. You should add some iterator or variable to the row # of where you're pasting, so that it moves to the next empty row after copying the values.

Comment: I thought I was looping through and pasting the data into separate Cells; B24, C24, D24. Would this require individual For Loops for each one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your code with the added extra, of increasing row numbers on the import sheet for each new row of data, as well as avoiding the copy paste function.

```
Sub ImportData()

Dim FileOpen As Variant
Dim OpenBook As Workbook
Dim i As Integer
Dim RNmbr As Integer ' Row Number on the import sheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
FileOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your File & Import Range", FileFilter:="Excel Files(*.xls*),*xls*")

If FileOpen <> False Then

Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileOpen)

OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("E11:F100").Replace What:="U", Replacement:=""
OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("E11:F100").Replace What:="i", Replacement:=""

'Date & Time
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input").Range("B10").Value = OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("E9").Value
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input").Range("B11").Value = OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("E10").Value
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input").Range("C10").Value = OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("F9").Value
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input").Range("C11").Value = OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("F10").Value
'Plant Name
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input").Range("D11").Value = OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("B4").Value

'pH

RNmbr = 24 ' This is the starting row number

For i = 11 To 100
    If OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & i).Value = "Sales" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input").Range("B" & RNmbr).Value = OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 5).Value
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input").Range("C" & RNmbr).Value = OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 6).Value
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input").Range("D" & RNmbr).Value = OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 2).Value
        RNmbr = RNmbr + 1 ' increase the row number ready for the next set of data import
    End If
Next i  
  
OpenBook.Close False
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Please be aware, every time this script runs it will overwrite any data currently on the import sheet from the row number specified. If you want to keep previous data then you will need to find the last row of data and set that as the RNmb